# The quote symbol in LuaLatex

Tags: luatex, fontspec, ligatures

I have a document which are previously compiled with regular pdflatex with
`\usepackage{times}`, the typographic quote symbols are generated correctly as:

[image]

And once I started to use LuaLatex with:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times}
```

The quote symbols are generated as:

[image]

How come and how to fix this? Thanks!!

Comment: Update `fontspec` or use `\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times}`

Comment: yep, that works. You want to update this as an answer so I can accept? thx a lot.

Comment: Not worth it — this will almost certainly be closed as a duplicate when someone has time to find the place where the matter was addressed more fully.

Comment: You should first of all update your TeX distribution; the latest release of `fontspec` enables TeX ligatures by default.